# Simultaneous rotation of segments in pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame, physics, pymunk

How to make a boxed segment rotate, with constant angular velocity, about its combined center of mass (400,263.5) in pygame. The goal is to simultaneously rotate the four segments such that the boxed segment rotates as a unit while a dynamic body moves in it under the influence of gravity

Answer (score 0):

If you want the segments attached to each other all the time the easiest solution is to attach all 4 of them to the same body, and then rotate that body. To make it easy to figure out the actual rotation set the body position to the center (400,263.5), and adjust the segment endpoints to be relative to this point.

Something like this:

```
pts = [(-27, -238.5), (27,-238.5), (27,238.5), (-27,238.5)]
body_type=pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.KINEMATIC)  
body_type.position = (400, 263.5)  
space.add(body_type)
for i in range(4):
    segment = pymunk.Segment(body_type, pts[i], pts[(i+1)%4], 2)
    segment.elasticity = 0
    segment.friction=0
    space.add(segment)
```

Comment: How do I attach all 4 of them to the same body? I tried using joints but that does not give  a smooth rotation

Comment: Just use the same body for all 4 segments, I updated my answer with a example (untested)

Comment: Thank you! How do you recommend I rotate with a constant angular velocity. I am using the SimpleMotor function (shown below) but it is not working

`b0 = space.static_body,
motor = pymunk.constraint.SimpleMotor(b0, body_type, 0.3),
space.add(motor)`

Comment: That is because body_type is a kinematic body. You are supposed to control kinematic bodies from your code (by setting their velocity and/or angular_velocity). They can not be moved by any constraints or collisions and similar. So in your case just set `body_type.angular_velocity` to the speed you want.

Comment: The code given [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17AEZ276opbl40Jrh4Hao3rT7BhGXNDDf/view?usp=sharing) should work at this point but it is not for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. As you can tell, I am new to this whole animation space

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot to add the body_type Body to the space. All the bodies should normally be added to the space. I have updated my answer. (Next major version of Pymunk will include a check for this to make it easier to spot mistakes)